# Nginx auth_request handler accessing POST request body?

Tags: nginx, auth-request

I'm using Nginx (version 1.9.9) as a reverse proxy to my backend server. It needs to perform authentication/authorization based on the **contents** of the POST requests. And I'm having trouble reading the POST request body in my auth_request handler. Here's what I got.

Nginx configuration (relevant part):

```
server {
    location / {
        auth_request /auth-proxy;
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
    }

    location = /auth-proxy {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://auth-server/;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
        proxy_no_cache "1";
    }
}
```

And in my auth-server code (Python 2.7), I try to read the request body like this:

```
class AuthHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def get_request_body(self):
        content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
        content = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        return content
```

I printed out the content_len and it had the correct value. However, the self.rfile.read() will simply hang. And eventually it will time out and returns "[Errno 32] Broken pipe".

This is how I posted test data to the server:

```
$ curl --data '12345678' localhost:1234
```

The above command hangs as well and eventually times out and prints "Closing connection 0".

Any obvious mistakes in what I'm doing?

Thanks much!

Comment: Interestingly, if I use `curl` to post directly to my auth-server, it can read the request body just fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code of the nginx-auth-request-module is [annotated at nginx.com](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/examples/auth_request/). The module always replaces the POST body with an empty buffer.

In one of the [tutorials](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access-auth-request/), they explain the reason, stating:

> As the request body is discarded for authentication subrequests, you will 
>   need to set the proxy_pass_request_body directive to off and also set the 
>   Content-Length header to a null string

The reason for this is that auth subrequests are sent at HTTP GET methods, not POST. Since GET has no body, the body is discarded. The only workaround with the existing module would be to pull the needed information from the request body and put it into an HTTP header that is passed to the auth service.

Comment: How do you mean "to pull the needed information from the request body". I am stuck on this.

Comment: @Angshuman you could perhaps use the lua module to pre-process the request and read out part of the body, and add it as a header. Thee are probably other solutions as well, but authorization based on POST content with nginx-auth-request-module is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Unfortunately I will have to live with the existing modules. Let me know if you can think of other solutions.

Comment: The answer suggests a workaround, but I noticed that variables like `$request_body` and `$query_string` are not forwarded as headers (`proxy_set_header`) to the auth provider when the request to the auth provider is performed. Did no extensive testing, though.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the given task, you should use "ngx_http_lua_module" module, which enables the use of the Lua scripting language in Nginx to extend request processing functionality.
Using it, you should substitute HTTP request body in the header.

Enable module loading in `nginx.conf`:

```
load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;
...
http {
    init_by_lua 'cjson = require("cjson")';
    ...
}
```

modify the "location" section so that it looks like this:

```
location ~ ^/backend {
    rewrite_by_lua_block {
        ngx.req.read_body()
        local body_data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
        if body_data then
            local json_body = cjson.encode(body_data)
            ngx.req.set_header("X-Body", json_body)
        end
    }
    auth_request     /auth;
    ...
}
```

The Lua script can be placed in a separate file. Use `rewrite_by_lua_file` to specify the Lua file location.

```
location ~ ^/backend {
    rewrite_by_lua_file '/path/to/rewrite.lua';
    auth_request     /auth;
    ...
}
```

/path/to/rewrite.lua:

```
ngx.req.read_body()
local body_data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
if body_data then
    local json_body = cjson.encode(body_data)
    ngx.req.set_header("X-Body", json_body)
end
```

This also works for GraphQL requests.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `$request_body` variable is made available when the request body has been read into a memory buffer as mentioned in this doc:

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_body

Given this, I believe that if the use of the "ngx_http_lua_module" module is unfeasible, there is the possibility of a double proxy.

Example:

```
server {
  listen       443;
  ...

  location /backend1 {
    proxy_set_header X-Body $request_body;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/backend1;
  }
}

server {
  listen       8080;

  location /backend1 {
    auth_request /auth;
    proxy_pass http://backend1;
  }
}
```