# nginx cant send request body to upstream server

Tags: nginx, microservices

im using nginx as api gateway. and i have 3 microservices,

- auth service
- product service
- cart service

now im using auth_request module to check authentication and send a jwt token to microservice.
it's works fine. but in post request, request body is not passing to microservices.
i need to pass current request body to microservices.

example:
if i want to add items to cart, first check the authentication with auth service and new jwt header added to the request and send it to the cart service. but request body is not sending to cart service.

```
upstream auth-service {
  server 0.0.0.0:8000;
}

upstream products-service {
  server 0.0.0.0:6000;
}

upstream carts-service {
  server 0.0.0.0:7000;
}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    include mime.types;
    root /var/www/html;

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range";
    add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Length,Content-Range";
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000;


    #auth_request /_oauth2_token_introspection;

    location /api/auth {
        proxy_pass http://auth-service;
    }

    location /api/products {
        auth_request /_oauth2_token_introspection;
        auth_request_set $jwt_token $sent_http_jwt;
        proxy_set_header JWT $jwt_token;
        proxy_pass http://products-service;
    }

    location /api/carts {
        auth_request /_oauth2_token_introspection;
        auth_request_set $jwt_token $sent_http_jwt;
        proxy_set_header JWT $jwt_token;
        proxy_pass http://carts-service;
    }

    location = /_oauth2_token_introspection {
        internal;
        proxy_method      GET;
        proxy_set_header  Authorization "$http_authorization";
        proxy_set_header  Content-Type "application/json";
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_pass        http://auth-service/api/auth/user-jwt/;
    }
}
```

Comment: A wild guess - what if you explicitly add `proxy_pass_request_body on;` directive to `location /api/products { ... }` and `location /api/carts { ... }` blocks?

Comment: @IvanShatsky i added but it's not working

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645270/nginx-auth-request-handler-accessing-post-request-body