# Add a custom header while redirecting in NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to redirect all API calls to an authorization service endpoint using nginx. I will need to pass a custom header in which i intend to pass the original uri or $request_uri.
Trying the below:

```
location /api/other {`
    add_header X-Original_URI $request_uri
    return 308 https://example.com/myauthservice/api/authorize
}
```

unfortunately the header is not getting added, need some help to see if this is correct way to do.

I tried auth_request module, proxy_pass. auth_request I cannot use, as it cannot send $request_body. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645270/nginx-auth-request-handler-accessing-post-request-body), but not able store or capture the $request_body.

proxy_pass I am not able to use as it ends up like this:

`https://myauthservice/api/authorize/createuser`
where createuser is from `https://example.com/api/other/createuser`

Comment: Your custom header will be added to the `308 Permanent Redirect` response after the `Location` header, but that won't made the browser send that header as part of the request to `https://example.com/myauthservice/api/authorize` URI. I don't see any ways to do it but to proxy that request with the `proxy_pass` directive using something like `location /api/other { rewrite ^ / break; proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri; proxy_pass https://example.com/myauthservice/api/authorize; }`.

Comment: thanks for reply, this does not seem to work, throws 405 not allowed. because proxypass expects the argument.

Comment: But the `https://example.com/myauthservice/api/authorize` **is** an argument for `proxy_pass`, isn't it?

Comment: as far as i know it adds createuserat the end, if it does not see it, it is not happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent appending the `/createuser` suffix to the proxied request. As the `proxy_pass` documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> In some cases, the part of a request URI to be replaced cannot be determined:
>
> ...
>
> - When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a request (break):
>
>   ```
>   location /name/ {
>       rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
>   }
>   ```
>
>   In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the full changed request URI is passed to the server.

Try the following `location` block:

```
location /api/other {
    rewrite ^ /myauthservice/api/authorize break;
    proxy_set_header X-Original_URI $request_uri;
    proxy_pass https://example.com;
}
```